# Mount remote directory using SSH

Tags: mount, ssh, sshfs

How to mount a remote directory using `SSH` to be available  same as if it is  a local directory?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

First install the module:

```bash
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

Load it to kernel:

```bash
sudo modprobe fuse
```

Setting permissions (Ubuntu versions < 16.04):

```bash
sudo adduser $USER fuse
sudo chown root:fuse /dev/fuse
sudo chmod +x /dev/fusermount
```

Now we'll create a directory to mount the remote folder in.

I chose to create it in my home directory and call it `remoteDir`.

```bash
mkdir ~/remoteDir
```

Now I ran the command to mount it (mount on home):

```bash
sshfs maythux@192.168.xx.xx:/home/maythuxServ/Mounted ~/remoteDir
```

Now it should be mounted:

```bash
cd ~/remoteDir
ls -l
```

Comment: I'm a little confused... in the `sshfs` command, I think that the mountpoint local directory is named `remoteDir`, and when I'm on the ssh serever, there is a dir `/home/maythuxServ/Mounted` that is not mounted locally, and I can not tell, or care, whether it's mounted elsewhere?

Comment: I skipped some of these steps under 14.04 when I used the following guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS

Comment: No fuse group needed (Ubuntu 16.04, Nov 2017): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635631/ubuntu-15-10-no-fuse-group

Comment: Are these commands running on the client or the server?

Comment: On 18.04, I skipped the full 2nd block - setting permissions and it works fine.

Comment: Half of this answer either does not work or is outdated. Please consider updating.

Answer (score 33):

**Configure ssh key-based authentication**

Generate key pair on the local host.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Accept all sugestions with enter key.

Copy public key to the remote host:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host
```

**Install sshfs**

```
$ sudo apt install sshfs
```

**Mount remote directory**

```
$ sshfs user@host:/remote_directory /local_directory
```

**Don't try to add remote fs to /etc/fstab**

Or don't try to mount shares via /etc/rc.local .

In both cases it won't work as the network is not available when init reads /etc/fstab.

**Install AutoFS**

```
$ sudo apt install autofs
```

**Edit /etc/auto.master**

Comment out the following lines

```
#+/etc/auto.master.d
#+/etc/auto.master
```

Add a new line

```
/- /etc/auto.sshfs --timeout=30
```

Save and quit

**Edit /etc/auto.sshfs**

Add a new line

```
/local_directory -fstype=fuse,allow_other,IdentityFile=/local_private_key :sshfs\#user@remote_host\:/remote_directory
```

Remote user name is obligatory.

Save and quit

**Start autofs in debug mode**

```
$ sudo service autofs stop
$ sudo automount -vf
```

**Observe logs of the remote ssh server**

```
$ ssh user@remote_server
$ sudo tailf /var/log/secure
```

**Check content of the local directory**

You should see contents of the remote directory

**Start autofs in normal mode**

Stop AutoFS running in debug mode with CTRL-C .

Start AutoFS in normal mode

```
$ sudo service autofs start
```

**Enjoy**

(Tested on Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Still good on Ubuntu 18.04. Used it to mount a directory from a Raspberry Pi 2 on a PC. 
When issuing `sudo automount -vf`, if you get `1 remaining in /-` it is likely because you have already manually mounted the directory at step `Mount remote directory`. Rebooting should fix the issue.

Comment: the part about not adding stuff to /etc/fstab is wrong the option _netdev is made for this case.

Answer (score 17):

Based on my experiments, explicitly creating the fuse group and adding your user to it is NOT required to mount ssh file system.

To summarize, here are the steps copied from this page:

1. Install `sshfs`

`$ sudo apt-get install sshfs`

2.Create local mount point

`$ mkdir /home/johndoe/sshfs-path/`

3.Mount remote folder `/remote/path` to `/home/johndoe/sshfs-path/`

`$ sshfs  remoteuser@111.222.333.444:/remote/path /home/johndoe/sshfs-path/`

4. And finally, to umount ...

`$ fusermount -u /home/johndoe/sshfs-path/`

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 7):

Install sshfs

`sudo apt-get install sshfs`

Add to fstab:

```
<USER>@<SERVER_NAME>:<server_path> <local_path> fuse.sshfs delay_connect,_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,nonempty 0 0
```

Comment: Worked for me on Debian 11 but without `noempty`

Answer (score 4):

Although it is not answering your question exactly but I just wanted to mention that you can achieve the same goal using "sftp" as well. Just inside your file manager address bar type this command:

```
sftp://remoteuser@111.222.333.444/remote/path
```

Comment: you can but it's very slow compared to sshfs :)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to run sshfs mounts at startup is also by adding it to the `root` (or another user's) crontab, like this:

```
@reboot sshfs remoteuser@111.222.333.444:/remote/path /home/johndoe/sshfs-path/
```

And if you need to add a delay, you can use:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && sshfs remoteuser@111.222.333.444:/remote/path /home/johndoe/sshfs-path/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to warn that, it seems that by default **only the user which set up the mount** can access the remote directory.

I set up a remote directory, and create a crontab with `sudo crontab -e`. Later I found out the backup file didn't write the remote directory at all. Then I found out that I could not `cd` into the remote disk as `root` ! So eventually I create the same task with `crontab -e` and everything works as I expected.