# Accessing a remote file via ssh on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ssh, text

I have a text file on one of my computers that is running 12.04. I was planning to use ssh to allow for another computer to read this text file. The issue is that the system that I am working with is basically logging some information on this text file at real time. I need for the computer that is going to read this text file, to read the text file at real time as well.

I am not savvy at all with ssh, but I am familiar with ubuntu. If anyone can provide some insight as to how to do this, or if it is even possible to read this text file at real time while another system is logging info it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think so, Because my .txt file is a custom .txt file that needs to be checked, and this file is located on a separate computer. Reading the info off the text file is no problem either. I am looking for something more along the lines of accessing this file remotely without having to use the scp command to copy the file over constantly.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "read" the file?  If you just want to echo the contents back to the STDOUT, then this should do it.

```
ssh user@remoteHostName 'tail -f /myDirectory/myFile.txt'
```

That should work if you have SSH set up properly, "user" is a valid user on your remote host, and the `-f` flag on the `tail` command will allow it to view a file as it grows.

Comment: Let's say that after the file is being echoed out to the stdout, I should be able to read this in a c++ progam... how?

Comment: So are you saying that you want to echo it to another, local file?

Comment: Basically I want to read the contents of the file that is located on the other computer, and I have a c++ program that needs to read the contents line by line and perform some calculations to this info. I mean if I can just read stdout line by line it would work.

Comment: I guess you could try using `tee` to pipe the output from `tail` to a local file, have your C++ app read that. `ssh user@remoteHostName 'tail -f /myDirectory/myFile.txt ' | tee ~/myLocalFile.txt`

Comment: This sounds like it is going to work. Do you know what will happen if there is no info to tail? For example let's say my system has come to a hault and it is not logging info on the remote computer. Does that mean that the connection ends or it just simply waits for my system to continue logging info?

Comment: If tail is active it will continue logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sshfs`. [Install and setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412477/mount-remote-directory-using-ssh/412478#412478) sshfs.

After setting up sshfs add this 2 alias to your .bashrc.

```
alias fuse-mo='sshfs remote_user@remote_server:/home/ternovi/your_local_folder /home/remote_user/folder_with_file -o idmap=user -o reconnect'
alias fuse-um='fusermount -u /home/ternovi/your_local_folder'
```

Now create folder `/home/ternovi/your_local_folder` with desired path.

If you execute alias `fuse-mo`, `fuse` module will mount remote folder to your local folder, and you will see remote files on your local machine in `/home/ternovi/your_local_folder`. You can work with this files as they are local.

Alias `fuse-um` will unmount remote file system.

You can use `tail -f /home/ternovi/your_local_folder/file.txt` to see latest output to this file. Or you can use any `editor` you want.

For example open file in `vim`:

```
vim /home/ternovi/your_local_folder/file.txt
```

And you can type `:e` to reload current file.

Comment: Oh wow... I didn't know that this is possible...

Comment: I think this is more along the lines of what I need.
thank you for the info I will give this a shot and see how it works.
I might come to you for some help since I am not experienced with ssh at all.

Comment: Feel free to ask

Comment: So I followed the instructions on this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) to view the mount my drive/directory remotely but i am getting "cannot access folder: Permission Denied"