# Program that edits a file through ssh

Tags: 12.04, ssh, editing

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

I was wondering if there are programs which let you edit a file on a remote server through ssh. Basically what I'm looking for is the following:

There is a remote AIX server that contains a certain file (a perl script i.e.) and I want to edit it from my native machine (my Ubuntu). Is there a program which lets me edit the file (by first giving the IP and password of the remote server) and save the file on the server?

Ofcourse I could just edit the file on the remote server, but I was wondering if there exists something like the NppFTP plugin for Notepad++ on Windows. It doesn't matter if it is terminal (nano i.e.) or gui.

---

Solution 1:

```
ssh -X user@server gedit file.txt
```

This doesn't work because gedit is not installed on the remote server

Comment: gedit can do that. How to: http://thecodecentral.com/2010/04/02/use-gedit-as-remote-file-editor-via-ftp-and-ssh-ubuntu Mind you: most of these ftp/ssh editing methods do not work if you do not have permissions to edit (ie. need `sudo`).

Comment: But that's 8.04, I get stuck with step 1

Comment: Step 1 looks like Nautilus (file-> connect to server).

Comment: Uhu, that does the trick!

Comment: Also look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/501656/164083)

Comment: Looks interesting, will try this out! Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
vim scp://remoteuser@server.tld//path/to/document
```

More [info and examples](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim)

Comment: This opens a file called /tmp/vxTuIQp/0.pl and not my specified file?

Comment: When you save your work that local copy is sending to remote server and you will see something like

`:!scp -q '/tmp/vxTuIQp/0.pl' 'remoteuser@server.tld//path/to/document'`

Answer (score 1):

You can also install sshfs

Running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
sudo modprobe fuse
sudo addgroup yourlocalusername fuse
mkdir servermountfolder
sshfs yourusername@server:/path/to/file/  servermountfolder
```

Will mount the remote server into the servermountfolder on your desktop pc.
Where you can easily edit the file directly with any editor of your liking.

Comment: Yes, c0rp has already given that answer :)