# How do I share files between computers without using a password?

Tags: permissions

I am wondering how to eliminate the need for a password when sharing files between computers. I have tried changing the filesharing in properties. I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on the OS the other computer is using, since it does make a difference?!

Comment: thank you for taking the time to assist.  the other computers are also using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method. Another would be to use the 'connect to server' button after setting up passwordless SSH. Note that this will work if both computers are running a Linux flavor, but not between Windows and Ubuntu.

**Step 1:**Setup a passwordless SSH connection between the two computers: [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)

**Step 2:**Then mount the shared folder from the remote computer: [Mount remote directory using SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412477/mount-remote-directory-using-ssh)