# Configuring Eclipse/PyDev to work with projects on remote server and remote interpreter (workarounds and pitfalls)

Tags: 16.04, ssh, python, eclipse, lxc

Question duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693969/configuring-eclipse-pydev-to-work-with-projects-on-remote-server-and-remote-inte

**I have the following set up:**

1. Ubuntu 16.04-64 on host;
2. LXC container running Ubuntu 16.04-64 connected through ssh;
3. several django projects (pure django, django-cms, wagtail cms) located in separate dirs in the container inside /home/username/dir1, dir2, dir3;
4. each project dir has separate /env folder which holds virtualenv environments (dir1/env, dir2/env, dir3/env).

**I am trying to set up Eclipse(4.8.0) / PyDev(v.6.4.4.2018...) IDE on host to work on these projects. So far I came to the following solution:**

1. created ssh connection to container through RSE tools and imported each project dir (dir1, dir2, dir3) as PyDev Python projects to my workspace;
2. mounted the entire container fs to the local dir on host (using instructions from user https://askubuntu.com/users/700824/pnti, given here [Mount remote directory using SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412477/mount-remote-directory-using-ssh#412478));
3. provided path to python interpreters inside env folders and usr/lib/pythonX.X folders (in mounted container fs dir) through Properties > PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar settings.

**PyDev complains about not finding some *.py files inside /site-packages dir. I've checked manually - all the files seem to be there. "Packages" tab (first tab inside interpreter config window) is empty (cannot load data from provided directories including pip tools).** “Libraries” and “Forced builtins” tabs seem to be ok. According to my understanding virtualenv copies all packages to the environment and leaves no links to the base install.

**Questions:
 1. Is it just PyDev wrong error message or there is a chance that something is really missing in the env folder?
 2. Why pip tools were not found?
 3. Is it critical? I don't need pip integration and django integration - only debugging and code analysis functioning properly.
 4. Is there an easy way to test it?**

Thank you!

P.S.: I've read information from these questions:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019120/define-remote-interpreter-on-remote-linux-machine-using-pydev-and-rse-server;
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716662/eclipse-pydev-use-remote-interpreter/15360958#15360958;
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834870/eclipse-connect-to-custom-python-interpreter-with-pydev;
4. [Mount remote directory using SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412477/mount-remote-directory-using-ssh#412478)

Comment: The question seems to be not very popular...
My opinion:
It's easier to work with simple text editors (like nano or emacs or vim) and complement them with plugins or stand-alone tools. Old-school heavyweight IDEs are simply not catching up with the container revolution. I believe most of the developers are using some sort of containers for their development and testing servers. I prefer using nano or emacs with elpy plugin. If I needed something special like getting an object map of the entire project I would search for a specialized tool (any suggestions / advice?).