# How to create a shortcut of a remote folder?

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, lubuntu, virtualization, shared-folders

I have ubuntu-server running in VirtualBox. This VirtualBox is running on (L)ubuntu 20.04.

I want to create a shortcut for a folder present inside ubuntu-server within VirtualBox. I want to be able to access content of this folder from outside the virtual box (the host OS).

**edit1**: I was able to ssh into the folder via a GUI and also ssh-mount it using sshfs.

```
sshfs -p 3022 user@127.0.0.1:/var/www /home/username/Desktop/remote/ -o identityFile=/home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519

nautilus ssh://user@127.0.0.1:3022 &
```

But the problem is, I cannot view the content inside remote folder /var/www/

How can I resolve it? I have tried nautilus-admin to no avail.

**edit2**:

I checked permissions inside the remote directory and this is the output:

```
root@user-ubuntu-server:/# ls -la /var/www
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096 Aug 13 00:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 Aug 12 14:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Aug 12 23:46 html
drwxr-x---  5 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 13 04:08 your_domain
```

Comment: I would [ssh-mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412477/mount-remote-directory-using-ssh) the folder into the host

Comment: I edited my question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: please add the output of your servers `ls -la /var/www`. It looks like a permissions problem.

Comment: Can you please check edit 2?

Comment: I just needed to run `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/your_domain/`. It may be too dangerous to give all the permissions, but for me it's allright. Problem solved.